# Graphstream with Icons in same order

Tags: java, icons, graphstream

I need some help to use icons on my graph. To be exact I need two things:

1. Icons as nodes.
2. Icons beside the nodes.

So I need the things shown in the first and last picture at the top row from the [this](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation_1.0/#viewers) tutorial.

I think I have to write a stylesheet like:

```
String styleSheet = "node {size: 100px; fill-mode: image-scaled;}" +
                    "node.fun {fill-image: url('fun.gif');}" +
                    "node.dull {fill-image: url('images/head.png');" +
                    "}";
```

But somehow I don't get it running, I never get the icons.
Could someone show me an example with icons for both of my variants?

Secondly, I always have 5 Nodes. I get the following Form:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But the Order of the Nodes is different every time. I need the same order, because I want to draw more than 1 graph and want to compare them.

Comment: FYI, this question has been answered here: http://sympa.litislab.fr/sympa/arc/graphstream-users/2014-11/msg00001.html